# CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED after build on xcode4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Im having some trouble to get my app installed on my iphone just after I built my code in xcode. When the build has finished I get this error: "CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1". My certs are ok, as I just re-downloaded from apple's site because Im working on a different mac.

I've tried a lot of solutions I found on google: changed form "always accept" to "system default" on the cert trust section, re donwloaded the certs, create a new project and start all over again but nothing seems to work.

However, I'm able to create an IPA file and install it on my iphone using iTunes, is this ok?? Also the certs were correctly installed on the iphone as on the organizer and the phone recognizes them.

I really appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the provisioning profile, you also need to download and install your developer certificate and the Apple WWDR intermediate certificate from the Provisioning Portal. Follow the instructions in the 'Certificates' section of the provisioning portal. You need to download your developer and intermediate certificates and drag them into the Keychain application.